# Make Azure AD B2C Application a Multi-Tenant Application

Tags: .net, angularjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created an Azure AD B2C application using Angularjs and .Net. I have even used different `Identity Providers` for my application. The application is up and working fine and is healthy.

The problem is, I don't see any option in [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com) to make my application a Multi-Tenanted. I was able to do that easily while using Angular AD but not in B2C.

Since then, I am not able to give access to users from other Active Directories. Is there any way to achieve this target?

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, **Azure AD B2C does not support multi-tenancy nor does it support Azure AD as an IdP**.

Both of these features are available for you to vote and keep track on in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum:

- [Add an Azure AD Identity Provider](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9865695-add-an-azure-ad-identity-provider)
- [How to on Multitenant Applications Based on B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9849063-aadb2c-how-to-on-multi-tenant-applications-based)

Based on your description, seems like what you really want is the first, allowing users to sign in with their Azure AD credentials.

Multitenancy is more about allowing each customer to have their own instance of B2C with their own policy configuration which could include having their own Azure AD IdP or some other IdP.